# Good alternative for hamachi on Linux Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.10, alternative, glibc

Absolutely love the updated system, it boots faster and is less buggy overall, but due to glibc being updated to version 2.26, Hamachi no longer works, does anyone know of a good Linux alternative? I've looked everywhere, but I can only find cheap garbage that looks way out of date security wise. Anyone know a good alternative or an alternative way to host in general?

Comment: There are quite a few VPN clients, DuckDuck will provide a good search result. But, the VPN provider you use will [often] provide appropriate Linux files. AirVPN [for example] provide their own client. Also, `Network Connections`, once set up, works very well. This is how I connect.

Comment: Too bad that it's a paid client :( looked promising, I didn't find that whilst I was looking before

Comment: You can give teamviewer a try, which is free for private use.

Answer (score 1):

Zerotier One might be a good option. https://www.zerotier.com/

Answer (score 0):

- I have used ZeroTier in Windows10/Android/MacOS/iOS only , Officially they support Ubuntu too (Free OpenSource Client - only, gratis for 50 nodes, 1 admin, sign-in required to create network and approve joining)

  Installation instructions here: [zerotier.com/download/#downloadLinux](https://www.zerotier.com/download/#downloadLinux)
- Another option is Pure P2P VPN, not sure if it is same of what called IP-Over-P2P (IPOP)

  Check `gnunet-vpn` command which is provided by `gnunet-server` package.

  AFAIK, ZeroTier is also P2P VPN but they provide a server to work as web-manager, tracker and also a relay in case NAT traversal.
- You may also setup your own VPN server if you have some control on NAT settings.